# jQueryUI draggable doesn't work in Wordpress plugin

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm making a simple plugin in wordpress that shows a draggable element.Here is my code:

```
<?php
/** 
* @package jqcfc
*/
/*
Plugin Name: cfc jq
*/

function page_jq() {
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
#draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; background:#eee;}
</style>
    
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "draggable" class = "ui-widget-content">
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}

function loadui() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-draggable', false, array( 'jquery' ));
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-droppable', false, array( 'jquery' ));
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'loadui' );
add_shortcode( 'jqpage', 'page_jq') ;
?>
```

I load the short code **jqpage** in a wordpress page using elementor but dragging animation doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Yoou can't create an entire page using a shortcode like that, you'll end up with nested html and body tags leading to invalid HTML. Also shortcodes return their content as a string, you should never output directly in a shortcode

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I didn't know that. Then, how can I use short codes to output a jquery UI section of the page? I want to design the rest of the page using elementor and only present this jqueryUI section using my plugin.

Comment: I'm not familiar with jquery UI draggable, or if it's even a part of WordPress, but I do know that's not how shortcodes work, I'd suggest looking up a basic shortcode tutorial to cover the basics before moving on to adding javascript

Comment: hmm your enqueue script calls also don't need the extra parameters, `wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-draggable' );` and `wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-droppable' );` are what should be there, you only use the other parameters if you're registering and enqueuing a script at the same time, which you aren't. I also suspect you've not looked at your browser dev tools for the error messages, and haven't looked up how to use jQuery in WordPress ( I mention this because you used `$` without any wrappers which should not work )

Comment: Yes, that's right. Both jQuery and WordPress are new to me. I will look these up. thank you!